# Throughput: It is the no. of events happening per second. Your task: Let’s say the above metric is called throughput. Calculate 7 day rolling average

Tags: mysql

```
job_data
job_id: unique identifier of jobs
actor_id: unique identifier of actor
event: decision/skip/transfer
language: language of the content
time_spent: time spent to review the job in seconds
org: organization of the actor
ds: date in the yyyy/mm/dd format. It is stored in the form of text and we use presto to run. no need for date function
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE job_data
(
    ds DATE,
    job_id INT NOT NULL,
    actor_id INT NOT NULL,
    event VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    language VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    time_spent INT NOT NULL,
    org CHAR(2)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO job_data (ds, job_id, actor_id, event, language, time_spent, org)
VALUES ('2020-11-30', 21, 1001, 'skip', 'English', 15, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-30', 22, 1006, 'transfer', 'Arabic', 25, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-29', 23, 1003, 'decision', 'Persian', 20, 'C'),
    ('2020-11-28', 23, 1005,'transfer', 'Persian', 22, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-28', 25, 1002, 'decision', 'Hindi', 11, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-27', 11, 1007, 'decision', 'French', 104, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-26', 23, 1004, 'skip', 'Persian', 56, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-25', 20, 1003, 'transfer', 'Italian', 45, 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

is my answer right ?

```
select ds ,count(job_id) as job_nums,sum(time_spent) as total_time 
from job_data where ds >='2020-11-01'  and ds <='2020-11-30'
group by ds ;
```

```
select ds , 
trunc(sum(job_nums) over (order by ds rows between 6 preceding and current 
row)/sum(total_time),2) as 7day_rolling_average 
from job_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

> First Understand the given dataset briefly.

Number of jobs reviewed: Amount of jobs reviewed over time.
Your task: Calculate the number of jobs reviewed per hour per day for November 2020?

Throughput: It is the no. of events happening per second.
Your task: Let’s say the **above** metric is called throughput. Calculate 7 day rolling average of throughput

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT ds, COUNT(job_id) AS jobs, SUM(time_spent) AS times
FROM job_data
GROUP BY ds)
SELECT ds, SUM(jobs) OVER (ORDER BY ds ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 
SUM(total_time) OVER (ORDER BY ds ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
AS throughput_7d_rolling_avg FROM CTE
```